# Drawing a pattern using only a single loop

Tags: c++

I'm new at C++. I need help in this assignment question to draw an alternating pattern as such using only a single loop; I've tried myself a lot but all efforts in vain.

For input n = 5.

```
*_._.
**._.
***_.
****.
*****
****_
***._
**_._
*._._
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, i, j=0;
    cout<<"Enter n: \n";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1; i<=n;)
    {
        if (j<i)
        {
            cout<<"*";
            j++;
            continue;
        }
        if(j%2==0)
        {
            cout<<".";
            cout<<"_";
        }
        else
        {
         cout<<"_";
         cout<<".";
        }

        if(j==i)
        {
            j=0;
            i++;
            cout<<endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `std::string(number_of_characters, character_to_draw)` may be helpful.

Comment: Have you been taught about C style char arrays or`std::string` yet? What parts of C++ and its library can you use? There are many different ways to approach this but it depends on what background you currently have.

Comment: @doug we haven't studied C. We're programming in C++, not allowed to use arrays. and only few basic libraries have been introduced.

Comment: You have a starting point -- what results does it produce? What needs to be improved? Can you identify a "next step" that you are having trouble with? Can you narrow down your question to that next step?

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing `n*2-1` rows with `n` characters each. Usually you would loop over all the rows and then, in a nesteed loop, over all the columns. But you can also write this as one loop, essentially unnesting the nested loop:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;

    std::cout << "Enter n: \n";
    std::cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n * (n * 2 - 1); i++)
    {
        int row = i / n;
        int col = i % n;

        if (row < n)
        {
            if (col <= row)
            {
                std::cout << "*";
            }
            else if (col % 2)
            {
                std::cout << "_";
            }
            else 
            {
                std::cout << ".";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (col <= (2 * n - 2 - row))
            {
                std::cout << "*";
            }
            else if (col % 2)
            {
                std::cout << ".";
            }
            else 
            {
                std::cout << "_";
            }
        }

        if (col == n - 1) 
        {
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if I should add some comments or explain something.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string init("._._."); // will have to write a function that has a loop to make this string, idk how to do without loop maibe possible
    string temp(init.substr(1, init.length()-1));
    reverse(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    string rev("." + temp);
    vector<string> word;
    word.resize(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        init[i] = '*';
        rev[i] = '*';
        word[i] = init;
        word[word.size()-1-i] = rev;
    }

    copy(word.begin(),word.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n" ));

    return 0;
}
```

here with just one loop